# Difference between operator += and =+

Tags: java, operator-keyword

Can you clearly explain the difference between the operator += and the operator =+ ?
Obviously, both are shortcuts for a sum, but I don't get the meaning of "=+"

a += b is equivalent to a = a + b. But what is the equivalence of a =+ b ???

Here is the practical example:

```
public class SumOfSquares {

   private int[] inputArray;
   private Integer result;

   public SumOfSquares(int[] inputArray) {
      this.inputArray=inputArray;
      result = new Integer(0);
   }

   public Integer getResult () {
      for (int counter=0; counter<inputArray.length; counter++) {
     int currentNumber = inputArray[counter];
         result += currentNumber*currentNumber;
  }
  return result;
   }
}
```

`inputArray={1,2,3,4,5}`. Expected `result=55` (`1^2+2^2+3^2+4^2+5^2` = `1+4+9+16+25` = `55`)
If I replace `result += currentNumber*currentNumber;` by `result =+ currentNumber*currentNumber;`, I get a result of 25 instead of 55. I would like to understand why.

Comment: There is no such thing as `a = +b`. Did you mean `a = ++b` ?

Comment: Could you share reference to the =+ ?

Comment: didn't we have just this last week?

Answer (score 7):

`=+` is not an [operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html). You might be confusing it with the combination of the assignment `=` and the [unary `+` operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html), which will take the value as positive (doesn't change its sign, `+ (-3)` is still `-3`) and can be perfectly ommitted for integer values.

```
int a = 5;
int b = 3;

a = (+b); // a = 3
a = (-b); // a = -3
```

> + Unary plus operator; indicates positive value (numbers are positive without this, however)

Answer (score 2):

`a=+b` is the same as `a=0+b`, in other words, `a=b`

`=+` is not an operator. it is the assignment operator `=`, followed by a positive sign `+`. The `+` is applied to the variable to the right, so you can read it as `a= (+b)`.

Comment: @user2541597 Glad to help. You might as well accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`a -= b` is equivalent to `a = a - b`, and

`a =- b` is equivalent to `a = - b`

Answer (score 0):

No, both are not shortcuts for a sum. Have you tried =+ to see what it does?

Hint, try with =- to see what that does.